# How to make Column Frozen even if Cells are merged

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How to make Column Frozen in JQGRID when Merge Cells are already implemented?
When I used feature of JQGRID, it will make it but not properly. I need some good solution for making it frozen even if cells are merged.